# MVC Parallel transactions and session objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I can't get the session values when I start a different operation while an operation is in progress like below;

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/StartOperation',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { customerId: $("#txtCustomerId").val() },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $("#textlabel").text(error)
        },
        success: function (result) {
        $("#textlabel").text(result.Result)
        }
     });
```

Controller side;

```
public ActionResult StartOperation(string customerId)
    {
        Session["OperationId"] = "operationid";
        // Some web api transactions (This operations takes a few minutes.)

        var data = new { Result = "Operation Completed." };
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am sure about `Session["OperationId"]` is not null, and then I call my cancel action while web api transactions in progress;

```
 $(function () {
        $('#btnCancelLogin').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                url: '/Home/CancelOperation'
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller side;

```
public ActionResult CancelOperation()
{
  String operationId =  Session["OperationId"] as String // return null
  //Cancel operations
}
```

Why `Session["OperationId"]` is always null on `CancelOperation()` method ?  Thanks for advices.

Comment: Try : `(String)Session["OperationId"]`

Comment: @SajalS, didnt work, Besides I tried without casting but Session["OperationId"] was null.

Comment: Could you open the browser console and check if Session[Key] is actually created during StartOperation method?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about Session["OperaionId"]  is actually created Before call CancelOperation method.   When I click cancel button after finish StartOperation, everything is work...

Comment: I'm not sure of this behavior. Since cancel would be a subsequent operation, you could try using TempData[key].

Comment: I tried TempData["Key"]  and returned null. When I used static variable it works well, but its not truthly.

Comment: I believe you need to write some code to enable sessions with web api. Please try to write the same code but with MVC controller returning Json(...) not web api controller. It must work. After that proceed to enable session with web api.

Answer (score 0):

if you take data from ajax side for start operation you should use post. Actually your ajax type is incorrect.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/StartOperation',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { customerId: $("#txtCustomerId").val() },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $("#textlabel").text(error)
        },
        success: function (result) {
        $("#textlabel").text(result.Result)
        }
     });
```

Or if you want to take data from controller you should return data

```
public ActionResult StartOperation(string customerId)
    {
        Session["OperationId"] = "operationid";
        // Some web api transactions
        return json(customerId);
    }
```

also your ajax should be like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: '/Home/StartOperation',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { customerId: $("#txtCustomerId").val() },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        $("#textlabel").text(error)
        },
        success: function (result) {
        $("#textlabel").text(result.Result)
        }
     });
```

Comment: I have already return json data after some web api transactions, I edit my post.